# Framework to test STUN/TURN/ICE protocols?

Tags: testing, performance-testing, stun, turn, ice-protocol

I need to test STUN/TURN/ICE protocols, is there any existing testing framework for this.
Like SIPp is there to test SIP scenarios, suggest anything similar to this for STUN/TURN/ICE protocols.

Answer (score 0):

SIP scenarios can't be compared with ICE connections scenarios.

However, if you want to check that a browser is able to connect to a STUN, or a TURN server (retrieving ICE candidates), there is the [Trickle ICE Demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/).